# The server has not found anything matching the requested URI node

Tags: node.js, express

I have below folder structure in VS2015:

[image: Folder structure for Node web app]

The server.js has below code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.port || 1337;    
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'client'));    
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'client', 'HTML1.html'));
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`listning on ${port}`);
})
```

and Html1.Html has below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head data-ng-app="imageLoaderApp">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
    <script src="/client/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('imageLoaderApp', []);
        app.controller('loadController', function ($scope) {
            console.log(`i'm here.'`);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm hitting below url in browser

http://localhost:1337/

I'm getting below error in console:

[image]

This is happening with all the js files. I even tried to move the html and js files in main folder still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: isn't `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'client'));` missing a / ? `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));   `

Comment: @lascort, didn't work

Comment: @lascort, it seems that it doesn't make any difference... Vee20's solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like HTML1.html is in the client folder. If that is the case I think you need to put the path to the js relative to it so: 'src="scripts/angular.js"'

Comment: Thanks... after this change had to restart node server.. For some reason it wasn't reflecting the change...